# Why is pyaudio not found even after I installed it?

Tags: python, pyaudio, modulenotfounderror

I have the following piece of code :

```
import speech_recognition as siri
listener = siri.Recognizer()
try:
    with siri.Microphone() as sources:
        print("Listening.")
        voice = listener.listen(sources)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        print(command)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

But, I am getting a `ModuleNotFound Error`

```
Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

But I already installed it:

```
Requirement already satisfied: PyAudio in 
c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (0.2.11)
```

Comment: Check if you can see `PyAudio` in the list of all modules by typing `help("modules")` in IDLE

Comment: what's your python version? Also do you have a 64 bit or 32 bit os?

Answer (score 0):

Go to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

Search alphabetically till you find Pyaudio.

Click on the link that matches your python version and os bit.

After the download is complete, go to downloads on your pc.

Open cmd there.

Run the command: pip install "filename"

For example: pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl

It should work!